# MacOS После обновления Remote Desktop Manager Free перестал передавать tab удаленному хосту по ssh

Tags: ssh, macos, desktop, tab, remote

У меня MacOS Monterey 12.0.1
Сегодня Remote Desktop Manager Free попросил обновится до 2022.1.13.0
после обновления подключаюсь к хосту по ssh - ok.
Пробую в ssh нажимать tab для подсказки значений и MacOS издает звук как-будто не знает или неправильная раскладка.
Раскладка правильная...

Подскажите что может быть и так и как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в общем сделал export всех своих групп с хостами в csv и далее
оправил в корзину.
затем заново установил

```
brew install --cask remote-desktop-manager-free
```

и все заработало как раньше,
кстати как оказалось версия 2022.1.15.0

```
VERSION 2022.1.15.0 (May 11th 2022)

Fixed "Antialias text" not being properly applied to SSH and Telnet sessions
Fixed "tab" key not working in SSH Shell and Terminal entries
```